# How can I load an STI record using just the base STI class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Say I have models using STI like so:

```rb
class MyBase < ApplicationRecord ; end
class MyBase::MySubclass1 < MyBase ; end
class MyBase::MySubclass2 < MyBase ; end
```

When I lookup records using the base class, the records all load with the class in the type column.

```rb
MyBase.all.to_a.map { |record| record.class.name }
# => [MyBase::MySubclass1, MyBase::MySubclass2]
```

99 times out of 100 this is a good thing, but is it possible to have these records load into their base class instead of the class in the type column? eg

```rb
MyBase.first.class
# => MyBase
```

I'm hoping there's a way to turn it off in the AR query, something like `MyBase.where(condition: :something, use_base: true)`...

My use case is that I'm using a gem which expects me to pass it an AR relation, looks at class.name, and breaks when it gets an STI subclass. To avoid patching the gem, I'd like to abide by its limitations and pass it a relation whose records' classes will automatically be coerced into the STI base class when loaded.

Comment: Don't think that it is possible to "load record using different class". But may you're going in wrong direction, trying to solve your real problem this way? Please, add more info about the gem and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I would type it all out, but the specifics are pretty complicated... Basically I have a gem I'm using that takes in an AR relation object, and tries to lookup other classes I'm expected to define using class.name. My base STI class has about a dozen classes inheriting it, and I'd like to not have to define a dozen more classes that are all almost the exact same. Tried dynamically creating those classes by doing using const_set and iterating over the leaves, but that doesn't work because my gem assumes that class.name is non-nil when the class is defined. tldr it's this or monkey-patch the gem.

Answer (score 2):

```
Myclass.all.map{|e| e.becomes(Myclass)}
```

will give objects of class Myclass regardless the type attribute.

Comment: This _almost_ works. I'm using a gem that expects me to give it an AR object, and calling `map{|e| e.becomes(MyClass)}` collapses the AR object into an array. My gem wants to call `join` or `includes` on what I pass it. Added that requirement to the question. I didn't think of using becomes though, and I might be able to do a more surgical monkey patch using it. Will see...